# Symbol output in vapply

Tags: r, apply, radix

I'm using a `vapply` to get a vector of characters, such as:

```r
vapply(X = 1:16,
       FUN = function(X) {paste0("status", X)}, 
       FUN.VALUE = character(1))

#>  [1] "status1"  "status2"  "status3"  "status4"  "status5"  "status6" 
#>  [7] "status7"  "status8"  "status9"  "status10" "status11" "status12"
#> [13] "status13" "status14" "status15" "status16"
```

Output included.

Say that instead of returning character variables, I want to return symbols (or object names), using `sym()`, like:

```r
rlang::sym("status1")
#> status1
```

But what if I want to return a symbol as a `vapply` output? I need to specify the output value type with the `FUN.VALUE = ...` argument, but I haven't been able to find a good example of how I would do this and my attempts with different variations of `FUN. VALUE = symbol(1)` or `FUN.VALUE = name(1)` have failed.

A desired output would look something like:

```r
[1] status1  status2  status3  status4  status5  status6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` can convert to symbol with `as.symbol`

```
lapply(X = 1:16,
   FUN = function(X) {as.symbol(paste0("status", X))})
```

Note that the `symbol` can only a `vector` of length 1.  So, if we use `vapply`, which returns a vector, it needs to be wrapped in a `list`

```
vapply(1:5, function(x) list(as.symbol(paste0("status", x))), FUN.VALUE = list(1))
#[[1]]
#status1

#[[2]]
#status2

#[[3]]
#status3

#[[4]]
#status4

#[[5]]
#status5
```

---

According to `?name`

> For is.name and is.symbol, a length-one logical vector with value TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Yes! I tried lapply, but I want a vector (and not a list) output.

Comment: @FelixT.  Even with `rlang::syms`, the output is a `list` `rlang::syms(c('status1', 'status2'))
[[1]]
status1

[[2]]
status2`

Comment: Ahh, I see! This is interesting- thanks for answering!